# How to automatically add characters to the user input before command execution

Tags: linux, bashrc, bash-alias

I love reading on the terminal - it focuses my attention and lets me read twice the amount I used to read on browsers, etc.

I wrote a script using alias for bash.bashrc that changes the working directory to the directory where I store .html files, and also displays the content of that directory:

```
alias la='ls -a'

alias books='
printf "\nA twilit bookshelf, somewhere\n\n"
cd data/data/com.termux/files/home/documents/books && la
printf "\n"'
```

And finally, I would like to add `'lynx '` after the prompt, so I could just type in the file name and read it in lynx.

I thought of the following presentation:

```
A twilit bookself, somewhere

.        kinglear.html
..       invisiblecities.html

admin@lib:/$ lynx [filename here]
```

How can I add "lynx " after the prompt?

Thank you!

Comment: Not actually an answer to your question, but easier solution, - install `mc`, run it and `cd` to your book directory and add it to `hotlist` (Ctrl+\ A). From now on you can hit "Ctrl+\" while in `mc`, choose memorized directory you want to jump, select `html` file you want to read and press `F3`, it will lunch `lynx` for you automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will just make a step by step instruction for a quick bash script I made.

```
cd ~/.local/bin
cat > searchlynx
(or use nano,vi,gedit or whatever you prefer)
```

**Paste following script with ctrl + shift + v**

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "\nA twilit bookshelf, somewhere\n\n"
cd /home/a/Downloads && ls -a
printf '\n'
echo 'Input filename:'
read -e FileName
FileFindTest="$(find ~/Downloads/"$FileName")"  ## quoted
echo "$FileFindTest"
echo 'Open with what program?'
read command
$command $FileName
```

Then press enter, and exit with ctrl + c.
You will then need to change permissions for the file.

```
chmod u+x searchlynx
```

***Usage:***

```
searchlynx
```

Directory will be listed, tab auto complete works on files in folder.
You will have to manually enter lynx, xdg-open or whatever after selecting which file to open.
I am tired, and I think the last part (tab completion of program to run) can be left as an exercise to you until I have more time on my hands. (hopefully you learn how to do it by looking at what I have done for you here now:)
I am interested in helping you solving the problem, but it may be a week or more until I have time to look at it again.

Please accept as an answer if it is good enough for you.
That will at least motivate me to help you tackle your last problem with the tab completion of the program names.

***Reference:***
[Can I implement tab autocomplete in a bash script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356075/can-i-implement-tab-autocomplete-in-a-bash-script)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed instruction!

I was aiming to keep the command prompt available so that if I would choose any other program to read a given file (.pdf file, for example), I could delete the automatically added 'lynx ' from the prompt and write the command for another program. That way, I could also hit TAB to auto-complete long file names.

Comment: Busy right now, will answer later today

Comment: Please explain better, I have a little trouble understanding what you mean

Comment: What I mean is that the user should see the files list of the directory, and have 'lynx ' already written for her in the prompt. It will her decision to just write any filename existing in the directory in order to view it via lynx -- or delete the 'lynx ' addition and write, for example, the command 'vim kinglear.html' to inspect the actual HTML script. Thank you.

Comment: Well, I don't see the need to have lynx filled in by default. If people are going to use other programs to open files, it will be more of a hassle to delete lynx if they are going to use vim, xdg-open etc. Will post updated script ASAP

Comment: Please accept answer, I will come back and help you with the tab autocompletion of lynx, xdg-open etc. IF you do. Its not a good feeling trying to help, when people don't want to reward people giving away of their free time.

Comment: Hey! Sorry for being late, how did it work out for you? Do you need more help?